# Get original cell data in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, click, cell

In my asp.net application, I'm using jqGrid and I am trying to trim the display text of a cell by terminating it with ...
Now, onSelectRow or by click on the message column cell, I want the original long message.

I tried duplicating the same column by giving different index name and kept it hidden. But here I am unable to retrieve cell data by index name.

Any idea here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by duplicating message column with different headertext in DataGrid so that name in colModel can be different. Kept this column hidden and retrieving full message from this hidden column.

Any other better solution will be appreciated.